# How to avoid leaks using EF Core's Context when returning a DbSet \ IQueryable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an architecture of `EntityManager`, on top of `EntityRepository`, on top of `EntityContext`.
For example:

Context:

```
public class ContactsContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<CompanyEntity> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

Repo:

```
public class ContactsRepository
{
    private readonly ContactsContextFactory m_contactsContextFactory;
    ...
    public IEnumerable<CompanyEntity> GetCompanies()
    {
            using (ContactsContext context = m_contactsContextFactory.Create())
            {
                    return context.Companies.ToList();
            }
    }
}
```

Manager:

```
public class ContactsManager
{
    private readonly ContactsRepository m_contactsRepository;
    ...
    public IEnumerable<CompanyEntity> GetCompanies(Predicate<CompanyEntity> p_predicate)
    {
            return m_contactsRepository.GetCompanies().Where(c => p_predicate(c));
    }
}
```

I want to gain a-bit more performance, thus I want to make the Repo to return `IQueryable` or maybe `DbSet` from the Context, so that the Manager will have the possibility the filter the list using SQL directly and not by getting everything first and then filtering.

1. Does that looks like a proper solution? Could you please
   elaborate regarding `DbSet` vs `IQueryable`?
2. As I see it, if I
   return a `DbSet` or `IQueryable`, then the resources of the context
   could not be freed (after `using` ends) since we still are going to
   query the DB (in the manager) - Am I correct? If yes, how can I
   overcome this issue? - **Actually, it throws an exception that the context has already been freed.**
3. Any other suggestions? I would be glad to
   hear. Thanks!

Comment: Is this for a Desktop or for a server based application?  Do you (want to) use DI?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, A server-based ASP.NET Core application.
The web-app and the db-server will be located on the same machine, and are not planned to be separated (if that makes difference)

Comment: Just let the DI container handle your resources.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a-bit? or send references

Comment: If you are using the repository pattern, you probably should be creating methods for everything you want to do instead of just passing a predicate to filter,  otherwise you're partially defeating the purpose of the pattern because you will be duplicating your predicates in the code

Comment: Hmm... that sounds about right. The thing is, that when an entity should be deleted, I don't really delete it, but I mark it as "not-active". I don't want the repo to be aware of it, so I query with predicates whenever I need only active / all entities...

Comment: A soft-delete feature is ususally exactly the responsibility of a Repository. Wher do you implement it then?

Comment: With the ASP.NET Core templates everything revolves around DI. The simple  `services.AddDbContext(...)` line takes care of allyour rresource issues. Easy to setup for non-Core and/or injecting your own Manager and Repo classes as well.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I've implemented soft-delete in the manager. Also, I will read about the resource management with ASP.NET. Thanks!